# Basis of vector space homomorphism between vector spaces $V$ and $W$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, linear-transformations

Let $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ be a basis of $k$-vector space $V$ and $(b_1,\ldots,b_n)$ be a basis of $k$-vector space $W$. I want to show, that $(f_{i,j}:V\to W)_{i,j}$ with $i \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$ and $j \in \{1,\ldots,m\}$ and $f_{i,j}(a_j) = \sigma_{i,j} b_i$ is basis of $\operatorname{Hom}_k(V,W)$

**My logic:**

We know, that $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ are independent of each other.

than we perform linear transformation for all $n$ vectors in $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$:

$f(a_1) = \sigma_{1,1} b_1 + \sigma_{2,1} b_2 +\cdots +\sigma_{m,1} b_m$, where first index is vector in codomain and second index is basis vector in domain.

and all $f(a_1)\cdots f(a_n)$ consists of linear combination of independent basis vector in W. It means, that each linear combination is unique. As result - $f(a_1)\cdots f(a_n)$ are independent of each other.

**Question**:is my proof correct? If not, give me a hint. If correct, maybe i should improve my logic a bit?

Comment: You seem to be using the lower-case $k$ to represent the field of scalars, but also to represent something else where you write $f_{i,j}(a_k) = \sigma_{i,k} b_j. \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Such equality was written in my exercise list. But I think they made a typo. I corrected. Please review my answer

Comment: I don't know what $\sigma_{i,j}$ means. If it's just any old constant then what you claim does not follow if any $\sigma_{i,j}=0$. As to your proof I don't see that you have proved either the linear independence of the $f_{i,j}$ or that they are a spanning set.